# position div next to another div

Tags: html, css

how can I accomplish the following effect:

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfPYS.png)

I have this:

```
<div id='div1'>
  text
  <div id='div2'>text</div>
</div>

#div1{
  text-align:center;
  background:blue;
  width:100px;
}

#div2{
  position: absolute;
  background:red;
  top:8px;
  left:108px;
}
```

But when the window is resized, div 2 moves relative to the window size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a container with a flexbox (see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and then position them that way. You could do it with positioning but that seems needlessly complicated for what you're trying to achieve and it'll create more problems as you resize the screen as you've discovered. Position is relative so as your screen size changes, so will your positioning. This method will give you more control over positioning elements if you want them in specific places and layouts.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

#div1 {
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

#div2 {
  background: red;
    margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div id='div2'>text</div>
    <div id='div1'>text</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This worked partly for what I want. I am using bootstrap, and when I use the code you sent, it eats part of the column and is a disproportionate layout.. like: https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/YJS0hE8bRUOAg5XTPHQ2sw.png @AStombaugh

Comment: @jacksonFive5 Apologies for the confusion, but you didn't mention that you were using Bootstrap in your post so I wrote out pure CSS. Bootstrap has its own classes and attributes so if you start adding things you may end up with some conflicts. If you haven't solved this yet, can you post a codepen with that content and I'll see if I can troubleshoot it from there? :)